# Firebase App Check isnt working on Flutter Android

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I was working on a flutter app that was working for both Android and IOS perfectly, including Firebase AppCheck Feature.

when I tried to release it to google play, I figured our that my package ID wasn't meeting the standarization. So, I had to change the Android Package (App ID), and consequently I had to remove the Firebase Android App from my project on the Firebase console and create a new one with the correct new package name (app id).

when I did that, everything is working correctly except the AppCheck feature from firebase.
App generates error message below once tries to connect to firestore. (as I enabled the enforcement)

> Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

the App check sees this attempts on the console statistics as "Unverified Invalid Requests"
with the description

> Requests with an invalid App Check token, which may be from an inauthentic client attempting to impersonate your app, or from emulated environments

*EDIT*
I found that this problem is only on debug build, release build is working correctly.
this is weired as I was working previously on debug build before creating the new app.

- the new app on Firebase console app check is shown as registred.
- I've revised that option play integrety is added and it has the SHA-256 Key (the same one I was using in the previous app before changing the package).

I expect it is something relateed to the SHA1 and SHA-256 but I can't understand what is the problem.
the keys I am using are the ones I was using in the old app, and I got it in the past using this command

```
keytool -list -v \-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

I am not sure should I redo this command before recreating a new app on firebase project or I not.
also on google play console I can see App Signing information, and it has different SHA1 and SHA-256 tham what I am using.

can anyone help me understand where the problem is?